# JS issue then creating a calculator and being able to type in multiple numbers

Tags: javascript, calculator

I have been following a video tutorial for creating a calculator, I have not completed the program yet, but I should be able to type multiple numbers on the calculator then pressing the buttons (without any addition, subtraction, multiplication or division, yet) but instead I get error messages, which I'm not sure how to fix. Can anyone help?

[Calculator link](https://code.sololearn.com/WBkSgB48DpWV/#html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dan, you should always have a look at the errors and try to figure out what's going on. Your error says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
Line: 22`

Which means, 'hey, something that you try to call `toString` on is actually not something like an object or value, but it is `undefined`.

Now you should go to line 22, which is:

`this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString();`

And try to figure out what is wrong - usually you use debugger for it, or just console.log, like this:

```js
appendNumber(number) {
  console.log('Current operand: ', this.currentOperand);
  console.log('Number: ', number);

  this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString();
}
```

In your case - `this.currentOperand` is `undefined`, since you never initialise it (it assigned in `calculator.clear`, but you never call it).

This fix will make you able to continue:

```
const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement);
calculator.clear()
```

Comment: Alex Brohshtut Thank you, it fixed the issue!